# Multi filtered ngFor List with search input box and check boxes

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a `ngFor` which takes an Observable with a list of courses. Above this list is a row of checkboxes which are successfully filtering the list when they are checked/unchecked. I am trying to add an Input box to search and filter the same list. Because the check boxes work by updating a `behaviour subject` which feeds the courses observable I can't get the filtering to work. I thought that the below code would filter and return the courses observable and it would automatically update in the template. But it is having no effect. I have put together a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rxjs-multi-option-filter). How do I filter the list with both checkboxes and the search input box?

```
textFilter(searchString: string) {
  console.log(searchString)
  return this.courses
  .pipe(map((courses) => courses.filter( course => 
     course.Name.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchString.toLowerCase()) !== -1))
  );
}
```

Comment: Check angular pipes. It's better to use them instead of filter in observable. RXJS operators should be used in case you want to split UI agnostic flow into 2 ways e.g. pastEvents and newEvents which will use the filter operator but not in case of UI based filtering e.g filter names by user input etc.
Check on: https://angular.io/guide/pipes

Comment: @RuslanGataullin, why would we use a pipe, angular team explicitly explains why they haven't created `filter` or `order` pipes: https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe

Comment: It's more of a recommendation rather than you should do it thing. And most of the downsides are related to the AngularJS times and it's change detection causing the performance drops(which was a problem, of course). Today you can use OnPush strategy and avoid such problems. Pipes approach though(in my opinion) is much cleaner and reusable than creating custom operators or dozens of functions/properties doing filtering/sorting which should bother subscribing or controlling the form state which sometime can result in a pretty large amounts of code.

Answer (score 5):

Try like this:

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rxjs-multi-option-filter-7t7aw9?embed=1&file=app/app.component.ts)**

```
  textFilter(searchString: string) {

    this.courses = this.courses
     .map(course => course.filter(item => item.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchString.toLowerCase())))
     };

  }
```

Comment: Good answer. Wouldn't we prefer this filtering logic in a service vs the component?

Comment: Yes, this can be refactored.

Comment: Thanks. I will probably place this in a service as mentioned but this works as I need it.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend to use a reactive form and no textFilter() method.

With the reactive form (which are your filter options) you have another observable `this.form.valueChanges`.

You can combine this Observable with your courses Observable like this:

```
this.filteredCourses$ = combineLatest([this.form.valueChanges, this.courses$]).pipe(
  map(([formValues, courses]) => doFilter(courses, formValues)),
);
```

Comment: Thank you. I will look into using combineLatest which may be the reactive way to go. I am accepting another answer because right now it works without me having to learn some rxjs.

Comment: The other answer is totally worth it, when you only want to do one filter at a time. When it comes to several filter options you should think about my recommended approach.

Comment: I am revisiting this answer as it appears the accepted answer works in Stackblitz but in my actual code it is not. I have tried the above code but I get an error 'Can not find name doFilter. What do I need to get that to work?

Comment: doFilter is only a placeholder. you need to apply your filter logic there. You could create a function named doFilter in your component which does it

Comment: thanks. I have created a Stackblitz that has my actual code which is different to the stackblitz connected to this question. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-e1t2yu It is not actually showing the data in Stackblitz but you can see what I am trying to do in the NgOnInit. In my actual code after typing 2 characters in the box I get an error 'Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined' which I think relates to line 59 in the new blitz. Thanks if you can help.

Comment: I removed a lot from your example to only show the courses. Check it out here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cwfvr2. Start typing for example 'i' and you will see

Comment: Or an example with multiple filter options https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fuy5j7

Comment: This is truly great, thanks @MoxxiManagarm. On your first example how do I make all the list show at the start when the page firsts loads. If I can crack this then I will be accepting your answer. Thanks